# AsyncTask result differs from regular function

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have a View that recieves swipe gestures. 
this should trigger the creation and setContentView(layout) for the main activity. 
(the View is within a Layout on the Main activity)

When i try to do this within an asynctask it leaves out all the images for the layout? 
as if it hasn't finished yet .
There is prolly something i'm not fully understanding .

this the partial code from the *view.java*

```
Main.mHandler.post(new Runnable()
                    { 
                        public void run()
                        {
                            new Main.GetNavigationLayout().execute(url);
                    }
                    });
```

the url is a location of an .xml file I use to create a new layout.

GetNavigationLayout is the AsyncTask

code that is the AsyncTask in Main.java :

```
public static class GetNavigationLayout extends AsyncTask<String, Void, CustomLayout> {
    boolean isDone = false; 
     @Override
        protected EvadoLayout doInBackground(String... url)
        {
            CustomLayout layout = new CustomLayout(Main);
                Looper.prepare();       
                try 
                {

                    String newpage = url[0];
                    Document doc = XmlImporter.GetNewPlayer(newpage);

                    if (doc == null)
                    {
                        layout = null; 
                    }       

                    layout.LoadXml(doc);  // cause drawing of objects etc. 



                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                isDone = true;
                //Looper.loop();   // causes it to never return...
            return layout;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(CustomLayout layout)
        {
            if (isDone)
              Main.setContentView(layout);
        }
 }
```

now this shows everythig besides images ,  whereas if i run this without AsyncTask it displays everything in the layout.
what am i missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  layout.LoadXml(doc);  // cause drawing of objects etc.
```

I reckon you are drawing the images here? I think this is the problem. Trying to draw from the AsyncTask's `doInBackground()` is wrong, since it is not the UI thread. You should do the drawing in `onPostExecute()` which runs in the UI thread

Comment: This works. Thank you.

It's to bad it works like this though, i was looking for a way to draw multiple layouts at the same time . (hence async).
I guess im gonna need some more test .
thanks ! 
then add them to a swipeView.

Comment: after some testing it looks like im running into a new problem ;

    10-05 16:32:28.730: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2024): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Only one Looper may be created per thread.

as far as i can tell im not declaring more loopers ? 
if I remove Looper.prepare(); the AsyncTask will crash ...

Answer (score 1):

You can post to the UI in the [onProgressUpdate()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onProgressUpdate%28Progress...%29). Using this method will allow you to stay inside the doInBackground and post an update to the UI when you get a layout and continue inside the doInBackground. Use [publishProgress()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#publishProgress%28Progress...%29) to send information from the doInBackground to the UI thread.

Comment: thanks man! 
I'll try this as soon as I get this looper error out of the way.
"Only one Looper may be created per thread" :\

Comment: You can remove the looper part it is not needed. The looper methods are only needed if you are trying to make ui changes from a different thread. You can remove the looper parts if you are going to be making ui changes in the onProgressUpdate.

Comment: Ok, so I've tried to do what you said , posting to UI in onProgressUpdate().  This works fine !  
However i cannot seem to get rid of the looper. 
"Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare() " error.  
also when i check the debugger I see that my AsyncTask don't get destroyed after use ? Is there a way for me to lose the thread after it is done ?

Comment: nevermind that handler part ! fixed ... still did some posting to UI :)